# What is the antonym of "to get used to"?

Tags: antonyms

I am looking for an antonym of the phrase "to get used to" in the sense of doing beginning (or in this case finishing) to do something oneself.

The only one i can think of is "to get out of the habit of".

In Russian there is a word "отвыкать", that has that meaning, but i wonder if there is a phrase or a word that has that exact sense.

Comment: Russian has a lot more productive morphology than English, so it's easy enough to find or make up words with specific meanings. English has practicly no productive morphology, so -- realistically -- _get out of the habit of `V`-ing_ is, in effect, the antonym of _get used to `V`-ing_.

Comment: break a habit ?

Comment: When you *get out of the habit* of snorting cocaine, you go through *withdrawals*. So perhaps "withdraw", or "disengage"?

Comment: To break an habit, one may use **disaccustom**. For a neophyte/beginner/newcomer , you may use **"take its first step"**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"**[Wean](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/wean)**" seems to be the closest word to what you're looking for:

> **wean somebody off/from something** (phrasal verb): to make someone
>   gradually stop doing something you disapprove of:
>
> *advice on how to wean yourself off nicotine*
>
> ---
>
> to detach from a source of dependence:
>
> *being weaned off the medication*
>
> *wean the bears from human food*
>
> [also](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wean) :  **to free from a usually unwholesome habit or interest**:
>
> *wean him off his excessive drinking*
>
> ***weaning them from habits of violence*** — Geoffrey Carnall

However, "*getting out of the habit of ...*" is a very clear and understandable phrase.

---

**Update:**

A few other alternatives from subscription-only LDOCE (See the last item which is quite an antonym, but still different in the meaning):

> **leave off** (phrasal verb): to stop doing something:
>
> *'Will you leave off nagging?' he snarled.*
>
> ---
>
> **break/kick a habit** (=stop doing something that is bad for you):
>
> *I've smoked for years, but I really want to kick the habit.*
>
> ---
>
> **unaccustomed** (formal) **unaccustomed to (doing) something**: not used to something:
>
> *a country boy, unaccustomed to city ways*
>
> *Register*: In everyday English, people usually say that they are **not used to** something rather than **unaccustomed to** it.

Comment: Yes, this is the expression that came to my mind, though 'opposites' are almost meaningless for complex structures. Isn't 'not get used to' an opposite?

Comment: Hmmm @EdwinAshworth, I think those two are slightly different. "Not get used to" somewhat indicates that you never got into the habit, where the O.P. is seeking for a word/phrase that explains giving up a habit after being in it for a while.

Comment: I'm not denying that; I'm saying that 'an antonym of the phrase "to get used to" ' is not a clearly defined concept.

Comment: Ah, right. S/he mention "getting out of the habit of" though. (:

Comment: Yes, I'm just hinting that your good answer would be even better if it pointed out OP's loose usage of 'antonym'.

Comment: Just noticed your last comment after updating my answer. I added a few other phrases and I think the last one implies that complexity.

Answer (score 4):

try [**dishabituate**](https://wordnik.com/words/dishabituate):

> To render unaccustomed to or unfamiliar with.

Comment: This word doesn't exist in LDOCE. [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dishabituate%2Cwean+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdishabituate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwean%20from%3B%2Cc0) isn't that positive about it either.

Comment: @Neeku "unfriend" was the 2009 Dictionary Word of the Year (see: http://edition.cnn.com/2009/TECH/11/17/unfriend.word/) but LDOCE doesn't reference it - http://www.ldoceonline.com/spellcheck/?q=unfriend . Dictionary.com dates the origin of "dishabituate" between 1865-70 http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dishabituate

Comment: Good point Paul. Thanks for the info and the links. (:

Answer (score 3):

There is really no good single English expression to convey the meaning of the Russian отвыкатъ/отвыкнутъ, unfortunately.  In part that is because a process is implied by the Russian--i.e., a habit or ability was acquired at some point, and then is was lost or lapsed.  So, to "no longer be in the habit of" or "grow out of the habit of," "grow unused to," etc. though clunky, are the closest in meaning.

I suggest using "*rusty*." For instance, you could say, in Russian, " I used to speak French fluently, but now I'm rusty," where "rusty" would be "отвык/ла".

Comment: Hi Emma, welcome to EL&U. I like your suggestion, but I added a paragraph break so it's easier to see where your background information ends and your answer begins. Hope you enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 2):

Depending heavily on the context that you're using it in (unfortunately don't know Russian, so can't glean from the word you supplied!), but *"getting rusty"* could be a possibility for colloquial speech:

> 1. I found using the Dvorak keyboard layout really hard at first but now **I've gotten used to it.**
> 2. I used to be able to type well using the Dvorak layout but now **I've gotten rusty.**

Answer (score 2):

"Get unused to it".

Although seemingly flippant, this should suffice and is perfectly understandable. 
It would typically be used by, for example, a superior in admonishing a soldier or worker to stop doing things in the manner to which he was accustomed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the trick is to find a synonym first, keeping in mind that "get used to" denotes a REFLEXIVE verb. I can get used to sashimi, but getting a friend comfortable with a raw fish dish is something else. In the first case I **adjust** or **acclimatize** to the exotic food, in the second case I can **acclimatize** the friend (the verb can be non-reflexive too) but the process is different--by some method or other you **convert** or **condition** the person. You can't REALLY **convert** or **condition** yourself...

The question as phrased seems to require reflexive only, so what is the opposite of **acclimatizing** to something? **Recoiling** from it? **Tiring** of it? **Diverging** from it? **Moving** beyond it? **Growing averse** to it?? The specific word would depend on the specific context, and the question is unfortunately general...

"I can **adjust** to sashimi, but I **cringe** at muktuk."

"I thought I was **acclimatized** to political attack ads, but I'm **seething** at the latest ones."

"Spent years **vegging** in front of the TV, but now I've **weaned** myself..."

Okay, maybe one CAN convert oneself, but there is some ambiguity here as to whether the psychology is active or passive...

Way-late PPS: Maybe I stumbled on it finally: **be discomfited by** http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discomfit

Comment: Do not **adjust** your friends! =]

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a specific example of what you want? "Doing, beginning, or finishing to do something oneself" is very general; and I normally use the phrase "to get used to" to mean "to become accustomed to", so I'm having trouble seeing what you are asking about.

Example: our first year graduate students are treated to a very nice picnic dinner shortly after they arrive. I usually say to them, "Don't get used to it. This is the last nice thing the department will do for you for the next six years." I mean: don't get accustomed to it.

*Accustomed*: Customary, habitual, usual. *Customary*: According to custom; commonly used or practised; usual, habitual, accustomed, wonted (obsolete use). [OED]

Synonyms (antonyms): general, ordinary (extraordinary), common (uncommon), frequent (infrequent), everyday, commonplace, conventional (unconvention), regular (irregular), stock (one-off) [Roget's 1911 via ARTFL Project]

Answer (score 0):

May I offer **uncomfortable**?

> My friend has *to get used to* gutting fish to eat. As it stands now, he is very *uncomfortable* doing that.

Comment: May I inquire as to why the downvote? To get used to is to become comfortable with.

Comment: Comfortable is helpful (hence my upvote) but not a verb. And a single-verb antonym is as difficult to find as a single-verb synonym...

Comment: @Kibitzologist I agree. Part of the problem is the be verb conjugation that is not inherent in most verbs.

Comment: Yep, that all-purpose "get" adds vast realms of vagueness. Is it lazy acceptance or painful adaptation we are talking about? Technically the opposite of both might be to get/be **discomfited** by...